# What is the bind function

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to learn angular2 with typescript and there is a code does I do not understand:

```
export var userServiceInjectables: Array<any> = [
  bind(UserService).toClass(UserService)
];
```

Could someone please explain me, what does code do?

Answer (score 2):

That's a very old way to define providers and is already removed in RC.6.

The current syntax is:

```
providers: [UserService]
```

or the long form

```
providers: [{provide: UserService, useClass: UserService}]
```